# In 3dmax Maxscript how do i run my macro or function, when user hide some object

Tags: maxscript

In Maxscript  how do I run my macro or function, when user hide some object or I bind my script with 3dmax hide action

Answer (score 1):

Register a [#nodeHide callback](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_C1F6495F_5831_4FC8_A00C_667C5F2EAE36_htm) with the function call as the script.